# Can Traveling into the past really change the future?

Tags: star-trek

Remembering one of two Original Star Trek series, Spock said that the past couldn't be change, Yet in the other one a science ship mate made it back to the time of WW II and the Enterprise was No longer there in there time  on that planet that had a Rock WormHole.

Comment: Yes, changes in the past affect the future. Every *Star Trek* episode that deals with time travel that I can think of (from the five live-action series, at least) has dealt with this problem